# Create Cron Job for send email with attachments files

Tags: laravel, cron

Hi how are things? I am new to the cron part and well, I have been resuming programming with laravel for a short time, I want to make a cron that I sent an email attaching a specific file that is in the database folder of the app, I know how to send an email with cron but I don't know how to attach any file, if you can help me with this, thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post only in English on Stackoverflow. If you'd also like to ask the question in Spanish, use [es.so]

Comment: "Tell me how to implement this" questions are off-topic in SO. Please ask specific questions about specific topics or difficulties with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have several attachments do this in controller:

```
 Mail::send('emails.myTestMail', $data, function($message) use($data, $files) {
     $message->to($data["email"], $data["email"])
                ->subject($data["title"]);
     foreach ($files as $file){
            $message->attach($file);
     }
 });
```